# Storing survey data in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

We are having a small form hosting application where number of answers for different forms are different. the current table structure to store the form answers as below.

```
------------------------------------------------------------  
|Survay_Id  | question_ID | submission_id | answer         |  
| 1         | 1           | 123           | test 1         |  
| 1         | 2           | 123           | test 2         |  
| 1         | 1           | 124           | tabc           |  
| 1         | 2           | 124           | xyza           |  
| 2         | 3           | 125           | xsfa           |  
| 2         | 4           | 125           | xsgffa         |  
| 2         | 5           | 125           | xsffa          |  
| 2         | 3           | 126           | xsffa          |  
| 2         | 4           | 126           | xssdgffa       |  
| 2         | 5           | 126           | xsdffa         |  
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

survey 1 has two questions and survey 2 has three questions. a unique submission is identified by submission id. 
questions

1) I can change the db structure slightly if needed. but it has to be SQL. as MongoDB is not yet approved to be used. is there any better structure.

2) what is the best way to query to generate a kind of report of submissions for a survey. I need something like

```
----------------------------------
|survery id  | answer 1 | answer 2| 
| 1          | test 1   | test 2  |
| 1          | tabc     | xyza    |
-----------------------------------

---------------------------------------------
|survery id  | answer 1 | answer 2| answer 3 |
| 2          | xsfa     | xsgffa  | xsffa    |
| 2          | xsffa    | xssdgffa| xsdffa   |
-----------------------------------
```

where we can transpose the table into the above view. any good way to do this?

if it helps the DB is MSSQL server

Comment: I think you need to use pivot

Comment: See this question for relevant information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708587/select-column-values-as-columns-using-pivot

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic pivot..

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB(Survay_Id INT, question_ID INT, submission_id INT, answer VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 1, 1, 123, 'test 1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 2, 123,'test 2'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 1,124,'tabc'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 2, 124,'xyza'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 3, 125,'xsfa'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 4, 125,'xsgffa'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 5, 125,'xsffa'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 3, 126,'xsffa'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 4, 126,'xssdgffa'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 5, 126,'xsdffa'
```

Now use dynamic pivot as below

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)='',@COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX)='';

--preparing column list to use in pivot
SELECT @COLUMNS = @COLUMNS+ ANS_ID FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT '[answer '+ 
CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY SUBMISSION_ID 
            ORDER BY (question_ID)) AS VARCHAR(5))+'],' AS ANS_ID
            FROM #TAB
)A


SELECT @COLUMNS = LEFT(@COLUMNS, LEN(@COLUMNS)-1)


--Dynamic Pivot Part
SELECT @SQL = 
'SELECT Survay_Id,'+@COLUMNS+' FROM (
SELECT Survay_Id,ANSWER, submission_id
, ''answer ''
+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(   PARTITION BY SUBMISSION_ID 
            ORDER BY (question_ID)) AS VARCHAR(5)) AS ANS_ID 
FROM #TAB
)A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ANSWER) for ANS_ID  IN('+@COLUMNS+')
)PV'

--PRINT @SQL

EXEC (@SQL)
```

**Result:**

```
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Survay_Id | answer 1 | answer 2 | answer 3 |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|         1 | test 1   | test 2   | NULL     |
|         1 | tabc     | xyza     | NULL     |
|         2 | xsfa     | xsgffa   | xsffa    |
|         2 | xsffa    | xssdgffa | xsdffa   |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1st output

```
SELECT Survay_Id,[answer 1],[answer 2] 
FROM (SELECT Survay_Id,answer, submission_id, 'answer '
+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY submission_id ORDER BY (question_ID)) AS VARCHAR(5)) as ans 
FROM TableName where Survay_Id = 1)test
PIVOT
(MAX(answer) for ans  IN([answer 1],[answer 2]))PIV
```

For 2nd output

```
SELECT Survay_Id,[answer 1],[answer 2],[answer 3] 
FROM (SELECT Survay_Id,answer, submission_id, 'answer '
+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY submission_id ORDER BY (question_ID)) AS VARCHAR(5)) as ans 
FROM TableName where Survay_Id = 2)test
PIVOT
(MAX(answer) for ans  IN([answer 1],[answer 2],[answer 3]))PIV
```